# Filezilla client vs filezilla server

Tags: filezilla

difference between filezilla client and filezilla server.I have been using filezilla client for past few days and while downloading Filezilla i come across two options filezilla client and file zilla server.After searching many sites for the info related to server,I am still unclear what is the exact use of filezilla server.I just know that if filezilla client is used to connect to a web server, FileZilla server is used ~as~ the Web Server; you can't connect to other web servers with it.
still i am bit confused with this answer/research????

Answer (score 13):

Firstly just to clarify, *FileZilla Server* is not a web server; it is an **FTP ([File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol))** server.

**FileZilla Server**

FileZilla Server is an application that acts as an FTP server.  Users can use a FTP client to connect to a FileZilla Server and download or upload files.  Users cannot use the FileZilla Server to connect to other servers - it only allows connections in.

**FileZilla Client**

FileZilla Client is an application that allows a user to connect to an FTP server.  Users can use the client to connect to any number of FTP server.  The clients allow users to upload or download files etc.

---

From your comments it appears that you need to use the *FileZilla Client*.  This will allow you to connect to a server via FTP and download/upload files as needed.

Answer (score 2):

filezilla server is not a web server it is an ftp server. thus if there a main computer in a LAN which can be used for supplying and receiving files. we can install filezilla in it and use it as a fileserver(FTP(file transfer protocol))

Comment: If I download the FileZilla application in my Mac, I can upload files to remote server now. But I dit not install the ftp server in the remote server, why it can upload success?

Answer (score 2):

Right ....but just to add to that answer, the filezilla client enables the end
user to connect to the filezilla server and gives him a convenient interface
to transfer files to and from from the filezilla server.
However for the filezilla client to connect to the filezilla server 
the client needs to know the FZ servers ip address and port on which 
it is running.

So a simple form of usage would be to map a directory on your local system to 
the user account on the filezilla server and connect via fileclient
to see the contents of that folder and then access it to download or upload
files across the network.
In case of any doubts please get back.